# What is the syntax of string concatenation in PHP while writing a sql query

Tags: php, sql

How do I concatenate a string with a PHP variable in a SQL query?

Example:

```
select User from users where id="badge_name""$user_id"
```

Please write a code example of concatenation for `badge_name` and `user_id` string.
Actually I forgot how I did this last time
It was like ."hello". With some other string. Please be more specific...
Thanks

Comment: it's the same as usual...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql_query = "
SELECT 
    `User` 
FROM 
    `users` 
WHERE 
     `id` = '" . $badge_name . $user_id "'
";
?>
```

Comment: That's more like it...Thanks

Comment: Sorry I to put another dot before last quotes, it should be like this: `id` = '" . $badge_name . $user_id . "'

Comment: Well I already got it...thanx , for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = "badge_name".$user_id;

mysqli_query("select User from users where id='$id'");
```